# How can I make an action to occur when two buttons are pressed at the same time?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-engine

I want my character to jump whenever I press two buttons at the same time. I've already tried this:

```
if rightButton.contains(location) && leftButton.contains(location) {
    character.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 50))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure in `GameViewController.swift` you have multitouch enabled.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ...

        if let view = self.view as! SKView?
        {
            // ...

            view.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

In `GameScene` give name to your buttons. On tap we will create a list of every node your fingers touched that has a name. If the list contains both right and left button, it means he pressed both at the same time.

```
class GameScene: SKScene
{
    override func didMove(to view: SKView)
    {
        // add name to each button

        left_button.name  = "left_button"
        right_button.name = "right_button"
    }

    func buttons_touched(_ touches: Set<UITouch>) -> [String]
    {
        // get the list of buttons we touched on each tap

        var button_list : [String] = []

        for touch in touches
        {
            let positionInScene = touch.location(in: self)
            let touchedNode = self.nodes(at: positionInScene)

            let buttons = touchedNode.compactMap { (node) -> String in
                node.name ?? ""
            }.filter({$0 != ""})

            button_list += buttons
        }

        return button_list
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) 
    {
        let buttons_tapped = buttons_touched(touches)

        if buttons_tapped.contains("right_button") && buttons_tapped.contains("left_button")
        {
            // jump code
        }
    }
}
```

You can simulate multitouch inside `Simulator` by holding `Option` button.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be:

- In your functions that detects the interaction with the button prepare it with a boolean.
- Then in your Update function, use a timer to add a range of time where we can say that both buttons are pressed at the same time (100 ms for example).

I'll let you here some pseudocode that I hope it helps.

```
    func RightBtnClick()->Void{
        rightBtnPressed = true
    }
    func LeftBtnClick()->Void{
        leftBtnPressed = true
    }

    func Start()->Void{
        rightBtnTimer = 0
        leftBtnTimer = 0
    }

    func Update(deltatime ms:float)->Void{
        if(rightBtnPressed){
            rightBtnTimer += ms;
            if(rightBtnTimer>100){
                rightBtnTimer = 0
                rightBtnPressed=false
            }
        }

        if(leftBtnPressed){
            leftBtnTimer += ms;
            if(leftBtnTimer>100){
                leftBtnTimer = 0
                leftBtnPressed=false
            }
        }

    // Lastly let's check if both are pressed.
        if(leftBtnPressed && rightBtnPressed){
            DoStuff()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would avoid placing checks inside of your update function,  you want to keep it as minimal as possible.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon You're right, I would do a function that only handle this kind of interactions in a PreUpdate function to have a more readable code.

Comment: No, you place it in a method that does not get called every update, like a closure in a run block